# A difficulty in understanding a statement in the method for finding all normal subgroups of the symmetric group $S_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I was reading this question :

[Normal subgroups of $S_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157876/normal-subgroups-of-s-4)

And I had a difficulty in understanding this statement:

"Now, any subgroup that contains all transpositions is the whole group."

Could anyone explain for me why this statement is true please?

Answer (score 4):

The transpositions generate the symmetric group: each permutation is a product
of transpositions. For example, a cycle
$$(a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_k)=(a_1\ a_2)(a_2\ a_3)\cdots(a_{k-1}\ a_k).$$

Comment: so he mean that any subgroup which contain $(12)(34)$ will generate the whole group and so it will be considered as a trivial normal subgroup?

Comment: all transpositions here mean $(12)(34)$?

Comment: but by this we will have 15 elements not 12 as he mentioned

Comment: "So we can consider only subgroups that don't contain the transpositions. Their order must be a divisor of 24, and since it does not have the transpositions, it is at most 12." this was a statement there also.

Comment: There are $6$ transpositions, but $(12)(34)$ is not a transposition.  It's the product of two separate transpositions, $(12)$ and $(34)$.  As for your last comment, since there's *some* element that's not in the subgroup, its order must be a divisor of $24$ that's less than $24$, which means it can't be any bigger than $12$.

Comment: why there are some elements that is not in the subgroup?@RobertShore

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the linked question states that if a subgroup $H$ of $S_4$ contains **all** transpositions $(i\,j)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, $j\ne i$ (there are $6$ such permutations because $(i\,j)=(j\,i)$), then $H=S_4$.
  It follows from the fact that any element (permutation) of the symmetric group $S_4$ (and more generaly $S_n$) is composition of a finite number of transpositions; in other words, transpositions of $S_4$ form a system of generators for $S_4$: explicitly 
$$\langle (1\,2),(1\,3),(1\,4),(2\,3),(2\,4),(3\,4)\rangle =S_4$$.