# Checking a normal subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Given the subgroup of $S_4$:
$$
V_4:=\{\text{id},(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23) \}
$$
How do I check if this is a normal subgroup? I know that to be the case it has to hold that
$$
\forall\sigma\in S_4: \sigma V_4=V_4 \sigma
$$
this is equivalent to
$$
\sigma V_4\sigma^{-1} \subset V_4
$$
I just don't know how to check this. It would be clear if a $\sigma$ would be given, but can I just use any $\sigma$? What I also know is that $(12)(34)=(34)(12)$ that follows from trying out or using the characterization of disjunct cycles. So basicly $(12)(34)=((12)(34))^{-1}$. So for $\sigma (12)(34)=(12)(34)\sigma \Leftrightarrow (12)(34) \sigma (12)(34)=\sigma$ if we "add" $(12)(34)$ from the left right? That would work for the other elements as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Note that [conjugate permutations have the same cycle type](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157876/normal-subgroups-of-s-4

Comment: Hint: Conjugation in $S_n$ respects cycle structure. Your subgroup contains all elements that are products of two disjoint transpositions.