# Is there a homomorphism $f: S_7 \to S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I encountered this question but can't figure out the answer + the reasoning.

I'd also be interested in a more general answer to this question regarding homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $S_m$ for arbitrary $n,m$ if there is one. (Or at least: In which cases does such a homomorphism $f$ definitely not exist?)

Comment: There is a natural injection when $n\le m$.

Comment: The kernel would have to be trivial or $A_7$.  Of course there are plenty of such maps that factor through the sign map.

Comment: I think you meant to add some restrictions to the map.  Obviously, there is always the trival homomorphism, so I guess you meant "non-trivial".  But do you consider maps that factor through sign to be trivial?  They sure aren't very interesting.  And that's really all you get in the case where you can't inject.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36452/explicit-description-of-all-morphisms-between-symmetric-groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Assume $n≥5$ so the only normal subgroups of $S_n$ are the trivial ones and $A_n$.

It follows that maps $S_n\to S_m$ (or to any image group) are either injections, trivial, or factor through the quotient map to the group of order $2$.  As $S_m$ will, generally, have many elements of order $2$, there are many maps of the last type.

For completeness, let's consider the consider the cases where $n≤4$.  As before, this is just a matter of listing the non-trivial normal subgroups.

$S_2$ is abelian of order $2$, $S_3$ has only the cyclic group of order $3$ as a normal subgroup.

$S_4$ has $A_4$, of course, but it also has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $V_4$, the Klein group of order $4$.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157876/normal-subgroups-of-s-4) for a discussion.  The quotient is a copy of $S_3$ which gives us another class of homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $S_n$ (or to any image group).  Of course, for $n≥3$, $S_n$ does have subgroups isomorphic to $S_3$.